# How to use tensor cores in pytorch and tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I am using a Nvidia RTX GPU with tensor cores, I want to make sure pytorch/tensorflow is utilizing its tensor cores. I noticed in few articles that the tensor cores are used to process float16 and by default pytorch/tensorflow uses float32. They have introduced some lib that does "mixed precision and distributed training". It is a somewhat old answer. I want to know if pytorch or tensorflow GPU now supports tensor core processing out of the box.

Comment: in pytorch you have to move your model to gpu using `.cuda()` method in model and inputs. then you can check the ussage in nvidia software `nvidia-smi`

Answer (score 2):

`Mixed Precision` is available in both libraries.

For pytorch it is `torch.cuda.amp`, AUTOMATIC MIXED PRECISION PACKAGE.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html.

Tensorflow has it here, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://nvidia.github.io/apex/amp.html) is a guide to use apex.amp (Automatic Mixed Precision), a tool to enable Tensor Core-accelerated training in only 3 lines of Python.

You can also check quick start for apex API [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex#quick-start)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32235828)